# Integrating Stripe on Rails 5. Error : Your card is not supported for this currency

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-5

I've installed the gem 'stripe-rails to integrate stripe into my rails project.

For some reason Stripe is constantly throwing me an error that reads "Your card is not supported for this currency." when I'm using their test cards

This is the JSON response body.

```
 {
  "error": {
  "message": "Your card is not supported for this currency.",
  "type": "card_error",
  "param": "number",
  "code": "card_declined",
  "decline_code": "currency_not_supported"
 }
}
```

My order controller.

```
 def create
   @order = Order.new(product_id: params[:product_id])
   @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
   stripe_token = params[:stripeToken]
   payment_type = params[:stripeTokenType]
   customer_email = params[:stripeEmail]
   Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe.secret_key
   Stripe::Charge.create (
   amount: @product.price* 100,
   currency:"sgd",
   source: stripe_token
   )
 end
```

The form to submit stripe payment.

```
                 <%= form_for [@product, Order.new], method: :post do %>
                  <script
                    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
                    data-key="pk_test_pTJ7JEFGxnr5gdgtDG33ZhTt"
                    data-amount=<%= @product.price * 100 %>
                    data-name="Fruit Ninja"
                    data-description="Buy <%= @product.name %>"
                    data-image="https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png"
                    data-locale="auto">
                  </script>
                <% end %>
```

I've added the javascript script tag which Stripe provides in application.html.erb

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

I've tried all the test cards but seem to be getting thrown the same error.

Comment: Have you gone through this? - [i]https://support.stripe.com/questions/what-happens-if-a-customer-uses-an-unsupported-card-for-a-foreign-currency-transa[/i]

Comment: I'm testing though, the default 42424242424242 card stripe gives for testing  is throwing that error

Comment: Are you sure your test card is correct? https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards

Comment: Go to: https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards or https://stripe.com/docs/testing#international-cards

Answer (score 2):

thanks everyone for your replies. I realized changing my country in business settings to US solved the issue. For some reason Stripe test cards do not work in Singapore. I've tried every single card including

```
4000007020000003
```

which was returning an error. The only apparent solution was changing my location. I've emailed stripe support.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#international-cards), you'd need to use the test card `4000007020000003` if you'd like to test with SGD (Singapore Dollars). Check the "Asia-Pacific" tab there for the exact details.